# Custom URL Expiration Settings in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a requirement to set URL expiration to 24 hours, but the system only lets me choose a timeframe between 60-730 days:

> Administrators can set links to expire in email sends at any point between 60 and 730 days or 2 years.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_url_expiration.htm&type=5

I am trying to figure out an alternative way to make this work - any ideas or experience in this area? 
Please note that this is not a one-off send, where I could simply re-publish the landing page after 24 hours, this solution will be a part of an automated process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write the sendtime along with the subscriber key (or any other unique identifier) to a data extension at send time (via ampscript). The subscriber key (or the other id you chose) needs to be passed to the landing page via URL-parameter then.

On the landing page you need to perform a lookup via the subscriber key (or other id) and check if the page should be expired. If the timestamp is older than 24h, no id has been supplied via parameter or the given id is invalid/not in the data extension, you redirect the user.

**Helpful resources:**

- [InsertDE - use in your email](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertde.htm)
- [QueryParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/queryparameter.htm)
- [Redirect](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirect.htm)
- [Lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm)
- [DateDiff](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DateDiff.htm)